# Middle click on touch pad not working

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I just got a new XPS 13, with Ubuntu installed. I tried to use a 3-finger-tap as a middle-click, but it didn't work, here are my synclient settings now:

> ```
> LeftEdge                = 48
> RightEdge               = 1168
> TopEdge                 = 36
> BottomEdge              = 644
> FingerLow               = 25
> FingerHigh              = 30
> MaxTapTime              = 180
> MaxTapMove              = 61
> MaxDoubleTapTime        = 100
> SingleTapTimeout        = 180
> ClickTime               = 100
> EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
> EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
> EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
> VertScrollDelta         = -27
> HorizScrollDelta        = -27
> VertEdgeScroll          = 0
> HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
> CornerCoasting          = 0
> VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
> HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
> MinSpeed                = 1
> MaxSpeed                = 1.75
> AccelFactor             = 0.143575
> TouchpadOff             = 0
> LockedDrags             = 0
> LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
> RTCornerButton          = 2
> RBCornerButton          = 3
> LTCornerButton          = 0
> LBCornerButton          = 0
> TapButton1              = 1
> TapButton2              = 3
> TapButton3              = 2
> ClickFinger1            = 1
> ClickFinger2            = 3
> ClickFinger3            = 0
> CircularScrolling       = 0
> CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
> CircScrollTrigger       = 0
> CircularPad             = 0
> PalmDetect              = 1
> PalmMinWidth            = 10
> PalmMinZ                = 200
> CoastingSpeed           = 20
> CoastingFriction        = 50
> PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
> PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
> PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
> PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
> ResolutionDetect        = 1
> GrabEventDevice         = 0
> TapAndDragGesture       = 1
> AreaLeftEdge            = 0
> AreaRightEdge           = 0
> AreaTopEdge             = 0
> AreaBottomEdge          = 0
> HorizHysteresis         = 6
> VertHysteresis          = 6
> ClickPad                = 1
> RightButtonAreaLeft     = 608
> RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
> RightButtonAreaTop      = 557
> RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
> MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
> MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
> MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
> MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
> ```

Comment: same problem here, any solutions so far?

Comment: After I applied those settings, they did not work. However, putting the computer to sleep and waking it up again activates them! It's extremely weird, but that's how it worked with me. @ChristianStump